# UIImageView fade out

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

In my main storyboard I have a `UIViewController` with a hidden `UIImageView`. I read in a thread that to fade an image out I could use the following code. I was wondering how to tie the `UIImageView` I created with an `IBAction`.

```
-(IBAction)popupImage
{
    _imageView.hidden = NO;
    _imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    // Then fades it away after 2 seconds (the cross-fade animation will take 0.5s)
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:2.0 options:0 animations:^{
        // Animate the alpha value of your imageView from 1.0 to 0.0 here
        _imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Once the animation is completed and the alpha has gone to 0.0, hide the view for good
        _imageView.hidden = YES;
    }];
}
```

Do I create a `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;` connected to the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the assistant editor

[image]

and ctrl-drag form the `UIImageView` to the top of your file to make an IBOutlet called `imageView`. You can invoke (call) your method in one of these ways:

- If you want to fade the image when someone clicks a button, ctrl-drag from a UIButton to the `popupImage` method to make an `IBAction`.
- If you want to fade the image programatically, just do `[self popupImage]` from wherever in your code you want the fade to begin (in `viewDidLoad`, for example). In this case, you don't need the `IBAction` part of your method, and can just call it `- (void)popupImage`.

Since you want to show your image from the beginning, you should not have it set to hidden.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to show the image on load and fade out to the viewController. I did connect it doing the drag but the code to show the image and fade out is not working.

Comment: Are you invoking the method?

Comment: I have that method in my .M file after the viewDidload. What do you mean "invoke"? Sorry still pretty new to objective-C

Comment: Updated my answer. Don't worry about it, everyone is new to something.

Comment: If you are wondering wether or not your method is being called, just put NSLog(@"It worked") in the beginning of your popupImage method and look for the log when running it.

Comment: Thanks. The method is logging that it worked but the actual effect is not working. I set the image to not hidden but on load its not there. I guess the method is wrong somewhere.

Comment: no. If I take out  `[UIView animateWithDuration ......]` part of the method it shows so I think I will have to look at that chuck of code to see the issue.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with you animation. Are you saying that you have hidden set to NO and alpha set to 1.0 in the Interface Builder, and the image still isn't visible before calling popupImage?

Answer (score 1):

You're using storyboards, so control-drag the UIImageView into your interface. The property need not be strong--it should read: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView`.

If you don't know how to control-drag, this video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq-a7e_l_4I. Fast-forward to 2:05.

Comment: That video was made by me :). I am glad people find it useful.