# iOS Frameworks needed for animation

Tags: ios, animation, frameworks

I have a simple animation to fade out an image but it is not working. The method is being called but no animation. What frameworks are required in the project for this? Think that might be the issue since the image just goes right to alpha:0 with no animation.

```
    #import "TutorialViewController.h"

@interface TutorialViewController ()

@end

@implementation TutorialViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self popupImage];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)popupImage
{
    NSLog(@"It worked");
    _imageView.hidden = NO;
    _imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    // Then fades it away after 2 seconds (the cross-fade animation will take 0.5s)
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
     delay:2
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
            _imageView.alpha = .0f;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Once the animation is completed and the alpha has gone to 0.0, hide the view for good
        _imageView.hidden = NO;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the popupImage method on the main thread?

Comment: Sorry, updated my code @AntonHolmquist

Comment: You can't do that in `viewDidLoad`. Try `viewDidAppear` and read about view controller's view events.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist I got it working but only on viewdidAppear. Why is that?? I thought viewdidLoad would be the right way

Comment: Have you tried moving the [self popupImage] call to viewDidAppear: instead of viewDidLoad:? That could be the issue since the view isn't  completely set up in viewDidLoad: so it would just go through the animation and finish at 0 alpha before the view actually appears

Comment: Ya I got it working in viewDidAppear just was wondering the reason why so thank you for the explination @sfeuerstein

Comment: Don't do duplicate questions, you could have just edited your initial question :) I'm glad you got it working though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209678/uiimageview-fade-out/25210086?noredirect=1#comment39264015_25210086

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was preferred to start a new question for a new problem. I will delete this thread. @daniellarsson